# How to search through a translated entity in shopware 6?

Tags: shopware, dbal

We want to search for the translated name in Shopware 6 programatically and came up with this:

```
$criteria = (new Criteria())
   ->addAssociation('property_group_option_translation.name')
   ->addFilter(new EqualsFilter('name', $value))
   ->addFilter(new EqualsFilter('id', $propertyGroupId));

return $this->propertyGroupOptionRepository->search($criteria, Context::createDefaultContext())->getEntities()->first();
```

But we get

> Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Dbal\Exception\UnmappedFieldException : Field "name" in entity "property_group_option" was not found.

How to search for a translated entity in general and in this specific case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT:

**This should be working**

```
$criteria = (new Criteria())
    ->addAssociation('property_group_option_translation')
    ->addFilter(new EqualsFilter('property_group_id', $propertyGroupId))
    ->addFilter(new EqualsFilter('name', $value));
```

**Wrong old answer**

This is not working:

```
$criteria = (new Criteria())
    ->addFilter(new EqualsFilter('property_group_id', $propertyGroupId))
    ->getAssociation('property_group_option_translation')
       ->addFilter(new EqualsFilter('name', $value));
```

See also

https://stackoverflow.com/a/67649705/288568