# How can i make associations in Shopware 6?

Tags: php, symfony, shopware, dbal

Basically I want the same result that this SQL would return:

```
SELECT id FROM property_group_option opt
    LEFT JOIN property_group_option_translation tra 
        ON opt.id = tra.property_group_option_id
    WHERE opt.property_group_id = <id> AND tra.name = "<name>"
```

The way to go described in the [Shopware documentation](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/framework/data-handling/reading-data) does not seem to get the right result. I have tried the following:

```
$criteria = (new Criteria())
        ->addFilter(new EqualsFilter('property_group_id', $propertyGroupId))
        ->getAssociation('property_group_option_translation')
            ->addFilter(new EqualsFilter('name', $value));

$result = $this->propertyGroupOptionRepository->search($criteria, Context::createDefaultContext())->first()->getId();
```

I did find a workaround which does not seem to be the way to go (and is also not the best performing), but it did return the right result.

```
$criteria = (new Criteria());
$criteria->addFilter(new EqualsFilter('name', $value));
$criteria->getAssociation('property_group_option')
    ->addFilter(new EqualsFilter('groupId', $propertyGroupId));

$translation = $this->propertyGroupOptionTranslationRepository->search($criteria, Context::createDefaultContext())->first()

if($translation !== null) {
    $criteria = (new Criteria([$translation->get('propertyGroupOptionId')]));
    $result = $this->propertyGroupOptionRepository->search($criteria, Context::createDefaultContext())->first()->getId();
}
```

is there a proper solution for that?

Answer (score 1):

You are using the table name. Try to use the model name instead.

Comment: You mean `group.option.translation` insteda of `property_group_option_translation`- I think that is better, yes. Fortunately the resulting executed SQL seems to be the same :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `addAssociation()` first - `getAssociation()` seems to return a new `Criteria` instance which is later not used in the actual query, if the association did not exist before:

See [in the code](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/d6c853ca3b6b167d61d70e6329f4fcface5c5245/src/Core/Framework/DataAbstractionLayer/Search/Criteria.php#L225).

```
public function getAssociation(string $path): Criteria
{
    $parts = explode('.', $path);

    $criteria = $this;
    foreach ($parts as $part) {
        if ($part === 'extensions') {
            continue;
        }

        if (!$criteria->hasAssociation($part)) {
            $criteria->associations[$part] = new Criteria(); // this is returned, but not stored
        }

        $criteria = $criteria->associations[$part];
    }

    return $criteria;
}
```